# Issue with "color_to_pick_list" sorting on Prestashop 1.6.1.3

Tags: css, e-commerce, prestashop-1.6

I'm developing a Prestashop 1.6.1.3 webshop with the default "bootstrap" theme and have run into a problem with the preview of variation-values. It seems that the color "Red" and only that one gets mixed into the size-buttons. When manually removing every entry of the red variations it appears as expected, but after adding the red/size-combination manually it presents wrongfully again.

The list itself is made from a table without divs so it doesn't seem like a global css-rule could fix it. Each entry on the table does contain an ID though, e.g: `color_242 or color_131` which seems to be unique in each product. However, not representative of the ID that I've chosen under creation of the value. Could this be used for a css-sorting rule?

Scrot of the issue at hand:

[image]

The link for the red color seems correct;

```
~/index.php?id_product=23&controller=product&id_lang=1#/48-ringstr-49/10-color-red
```

Size 55; (blue is set as default color)

```
~/index.php?id_product=23&controller=product&id_lang=1#/51-ringstr-55/14-color-blue
```

Color purple;

```
~/index.php?id_product=23&controller=product&id_lang=1#/48-ringstr-49/32-color-purple
```

I'd be grateful for any help or pointers in the right direction - thanks!

Comment: I see also "blue" color mixed with sizes on your example. Also what type of attribute now choosen for "size" attribute? by default there are possible "dropdown" and "radio button", in your example it looks like you use "color or texture" type for size. I tested on default installation, there all ok with red color

Comment: Yes. I use textures for custom button. I made png's of all the sizes I needed and added them sequentially, but after the colors. It might be noted that I never edited the red color, since it came with the default attributes.

I'll try out removing all of the attributes and add them, since you had no problem on a clean install. Thanks!

Comment: that's the issue, you can't use type "textures" for sizes and get not mixed buttons. Imho in your situation be better just stylize sizes radio buttons to buttons with numbers